# IDENTITY() function in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I saw an SP where the identity function is called in the following manner:

```
select id = identity(10) ..... into ..... from ......
```

Can any one please let me know if I can pass only 1 or 2 parameters instead of the three parameters (the SEED, INCREMENT, datatype)?

Also if a column in a table is already defined as the identity doesnt it mean that it will automatically generate a unique sequence number? Then what exactly is the need for this identity() function?

Answer (score 1):

Sybase 12.0.1 documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?docset=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/sqlanywhere_en12/help_top_index.htm&docSetID=1744) says:

> IDENTITY function [Miscellaneous]
>
> Generates integer values, starting at 1, for each successive row in a
>   query. Its implementation is identical to that of the NUMBER function.
>
> Syntax
>
> IDENTITY( expression )  Parameters
>
> • expression   An expression. The expression is parsed, but is ignored
>   during the execution of the function.
>
> Returns
>
> INT
>
> Remarks
>
> The description of the IDENTITY function is the same as the
>   description of the NUMBER function.
>
> See also
>
> •NUMBER function [Miscellaneous]
>
> Standards and compatibility
>
> • SQL/2008   Vendor extension.
>
> Example
>
> The following statement returns a sequentially-numbered list of
>   employees.
>
> SELECT IDENTITY( 10 ), Surname FROM Employees;

Sybase, unlike MS SQL Server, only handles one argument.  The seed and increment are always 1.

If there are any identity columns in the data being selected then their values will be copied over.  The `IDENTITY` function allows you to create a new identity column in the output table.

Answer (score 0):

identity() is not the unique identifier. it just means that it counts up automatically. the PRIMARY KEY constraint would make a column unique in order to identify the rows

Comment: Ok fair enough. But the querry that I shared, the identity() function has been passed only one parameter. Then how do I know that whether it is the SEED that has been passed or the INCREMENT. Also even if it is one of those two, what becomes of the other one that has not been passed ? What value does it hold ?